# Error validating verification code when requesting Facebook Token Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook API for logging in users for my site. I am developing it in ASP.NET 4.5/C#.

I use server side to get the access token. Here's the part of the good that I get the exception from:

```
dynamic response = fb.Get("oauth/access_token",
    new  { 
     client_id = facebookAppId,
     redirect_uri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteUrl"] +
    "oauth-redirect/facebook/",
    client_secret = facebookSecret,
    code = facebookCode 
    });
```

When I try to login, I get the following exception:

> (OAuthException - #100) Error validating verification code. Please
>   make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the
>   OAuth dialog request

I viewed other related question about this subject, and I checked the end slash and tried with encoded URL, but nothing works.

The URL I pass for the **redirect_uri** parameter is (I run and test my site locally):

```
http://localhost:2194/oauth-redirect/facebook/
```

It worked before, but for some reason it doesn't work now. I am using the [Facebook SDK for .NET by Outercurve Foundation](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) version 7.0.6, which I installed via Nuget. Thanks.

The URL

Comment: What value does the parameter have in the actual login dialog URL? (Check address bar.)

Comment: You actually lead me to the solution. The URL wasn't built dynamically but encoded manually by myself in the link, and there I missed the end slash.